# How to create a virtual file as a memory buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, file

I wrote a tool in python that encrypts/decrypts files, but I want to open those files in nano without needing to create a plain text file. Is it possible to create a virtual file or similar that nano can interface with? The files can be hold in memory at once.

Comment: I recently went through something just like this in ruby. I tried experimenting with unnamed pipes and some other ways, but ended up just creating an in-memory file inside of `/dev/shm`, but that does make it linux-only.

Comment: Also, in my use case the encrypt/decrypt + edit all ran inside of docker, so I didn't have to worry as much about unecrypted stuff sticking around after execution.

Comment: Your hint brought me here: memfd_create(). The man page says it's like a regular file but anonymous and only lives in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, there are anonymous, in-memory files that behave like regular ones and can be created using os.memfd_create() (Python 3.8 and higher).

```
>>> fd = os.memfd_create('test_file')
>>> os.write(fd, b'This is a test file\n')
```

```
nano /proc/[pid]/fd/[fd]
It automatically disappears if closed.
```

```
>>> os.lseek(fd, 0, os.SEEK_SET)
>>> os.read(fd, 0x100)
b'This is a test file\nIt automatically disappears if closed.\n'
>>> os.close(fd)
```

More information here:

- [man page: memfd_create()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html)
- [python3 os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.memfd_create)